# Get list of all overlapping matches of 3 consecutive digits

Tags: python, regex, findall

From `'123456789'` I want to find all (overlapping) matches of `3 consecutive numbers`:

```
ListIWant = [123,234,345,456,567,678,789]
```

I tried:

```
print(re.compile(r"(\d){3}").findall('123456789'))
```

Output I currently get:

```
['3', '6', '9']
```

And also I want to know if there is something more efficient to **count the number of matches** instead of using `len(ListIWant)`

I'm learning English also, It will be grateful if you correct or suggest me better words/ways to express myself in this place.

Comment: **Solution:** `re.findall(r'(?=(\d{3}))', a)` gives `['123', '234', '345', '456', '567', '678', '789']`

Answer (score 2):

Use a comprehension to build your list:

```
s = '123456789'
w = 3  # window size
l = [int(s[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(s) - w + 1)]
```

```
>>> l
[123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a= '123456789'
ListIWant = []
for i, ele in enumerate(a):
    if i < len(a)-3:
        if (int(a[i+1]) == int(ele)+1) and (int(a[i+2]) == int(ele) + 2):
            ListIWant.append(int(ele+a[i+1]+a[i+2]))

    else:
        if (int(a[i+1]) == int(ele)+1) and (int(a[i+2]) == int(ele) + 2):
            ListIWant.append(int(ele+a[i+1]+a[i+2]))
        break
```

Output:

```
[123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789]
```